# How do I specify a custom face with font-lock-defaults?

Tags: font-lock, syntax-highlighting

If I define font lock keywords using existing faces, I can highlight the string 'foo'.

```el
(defconst my-mode-font-lock-keywords
  (list
   (cons "foo" 'font-lock-type-face)))

(define-derived-mode my-mode fundamental-mode "My mode"
  "A demo mode."
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(my-mode-font-lock-keywords)))
```

This highlights correctly:

[image: foo highlighted correctly]

However, if I define my own face:

```el
(defface my-mode-foo-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-preprocessor-face))
  "Face for highlighting 'foo'.")

(defconst my-mode-font-lock-keywords
  (list
   (cons "foo" 'my-mode-foo-face)))

(define-derived-mode my-mode fundamental-mode "My mode"
  "A demo mode."
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(my-mode-font-lock-keywords)))
```

No highlighting is applied:

[image: no highlighting]

How can I use `font-lock-defaults` with a face I've defined myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> value of `font-lock-type-face` the value is just the symbol `font-lock-type-face`. Now look at the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> value of `my-mode-foo-face`. Oh no! you can't! It's not a variable!

You need a variable to access your face. Declaring the `foo-face` face does not declare the `foo-face` variable.

Add `(defvar my-mode-foo-face 'my-mode-foo-face)` after the face definition and then font-lock can use your `my-mode-foo-face` var to access the `my-mode-foo-face` face. Confusing I know.

---

*Edit: there seems to be a better solution based on what font-lock.el says:*

```
;; Originally these variable values were face names such as `bold' etc.
;; Now we create our own faces, but we keep these variables for compatibility
;; and they give users another mechanism for changing face appearance.
;; We now allow a FACENAME in `font-lock-keywords' to be any expression that
;; returns a face.  So the easiest thing is to continue using these variables,
;; rather than sometimes evalling FACENAME and sometimes not.  sm.

;; Note that in new code, in the vast majority of cases there is no
;; need to create variables that specify face names.  Simply using
;; faces directly is enough.  Font-lock is not a template to be
;; followed in this area.
```

That may be Wilfred's solution of double quoting the face in the keywords.

Comment: Aha, so it's expecting a variable. `(cons "foo" ''my-mode-foo-face))` also works, but I'm not sure which is idiomatic.

Comment: Hmm, my answer seems to be the antiquated solution for the problem based on what I'm reading in `font-lock.el`

Comment: It's expecting an expression, actually, which it will evaluate. So you can also put some logic in there.

Comment: Even after using this solution (thank you, by the way), I was having issues with this.  Turns out that any change I made to my custom type face, I needed to restart Emacs to see it.  Took me a *very* long time to realise that!