# Why do some faces not work with font lock mode expressions?

Tags: font-lock

I'm trying to learn about font locking in my own custom major modes. I can get things working fine for the most part, keywords highlighted, `regexp-opt` matching strings, using capture groups within a regexp to highlight just the capture group, etc.

But I've noticed that some of the faces that I have tried (such as `dired-directory`) do not work in font lock expressions, even though other faces such as `font-lock-keyword-face` work fine in the same slot.

Reading the manual says that face variables should be faces that have a value property that evaluates to the face name. Sure enough, when I eval `font-lock-keyword-face`, the value is the same as the face name. But when I eval `dired-directory` face, its value is `nil`.

So it looks like the value `nil` is the proximal cause of the problem, and the answer to my question (kind of). But it's not really a good answer.

(1) Why doesn't the `dired-directory` face that I see listed with `list-faces-display` have a value the same as the face name?

(2) How can any mode use the face, if the font lock implementation requires that the face name symbol evaluates to the face name, when `dired-directory` face does not?

[Here is a link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/how-do-i-specify-a-custom-face-with-font-lock-defaults) in SX that touches on the same subject, but it mentions that the solution might be obsolete.

**Update**

Here is my code line that motivated the problem.

```
 ( ,(regexp-opt ct-mode-nset-keywords ) . font-lock-keyword-face)
```

(1) Using `font-lock-keyword-face` (with no quote) works. (2) Using `dired-directory` (with no quote) fails. (3) Thanks to @theldoria, using `'dired-directory` (with quote) works.

Here is what the manual says:

> 22.6.7 Faces for Font Lock
>
> Font Lock mode can highlight using any face, but Emacs defines several faces specifically for Font Lock to use to highlight text. These Font Lock faces are listed below. They can also be used by major modes for syntactic highlighting outside of Font Lock mode (see Major Mode Conventions).
>
> *Each of these symbols is both a face name, and a variable whose default value is the symbol itself*. Thus, the default value of font-lock-comment-face is font-lock-comment-face.

Thank you to everyone who responded -- I have a working syntax to use going forward. And sorry for the confusion using `dired-directory` as my example - it is both a face and a separate variable holding a directory (or nil). It would have been better for me to use `dired-flagged` or some other face from `list-faces-display`, which trigger a `void variable` error instead of nil.

But now I'm wondering if the face-symbol-with-variable-value model is somehow old or obsolete, even if it is in the manual. Font lock apparently *requires* that variable value one way or another (eg with a 'quoted-face-name), but other faces in the `list-faces-display` do not have that value property (eg. dired-flagged, avy-lead-face, etc).

Comment: Faces are *not* variables, they're some properties stored in the symbol plist of the face symbol in question.  Personally, I believe it to be a mistake to have permitted variables inside `font-lock-keywords` as it's just confusing people when they're using a face name that is no variable and get the syntax wrong...

Comment: You can quote the faces, e.g. `(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("^[ \t]*\\([^ \t\n]+\\)[ \t]+\\([[:alpha:]][^ \t\n]*\\)"
                               (1 'font-lock-keyword-face)
                               (2 'dired-directory))))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `dired-directory` does not have face `dired-directory` as its value.  Instead, it has a directory as its value (as you can see by `C-h v dired-directory`).

In general, faces are not associated with variables; that is, there is no variable whose value is a given face.  And it is generally recommended not to create and use a face-valued variable, just to be able to use its face.  Use the face directly, instead.

So for example, if you want to refer to face `dired-directory` then simply refer to that symbol.  In most contexts this means passing the quoted symbol, so that evaluation returns the symbol: **`'dired-directory`**.

Just remember the general rule that you should never (or nearly never) need to refer to a face-valued variable, just in order to refer to its (face) value.

In some older parts of Emacs, including font lock, there are still some face-valued variables, and this can confuse things.

Another, more legitimate use of a face-valued variable is a user option, whose value is intended to be changed (customized) from one face to another. In this case, the option name typically is **not**, and generally should **not** be, the name of any given face.